# Google Map doesn't load in Thickbox in IE8

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, compatibility, thickbox, google-maps-api-2

I have a Google Map (API v2).

It is located in http://mydomain/maps.
Under that address it works fine in every browser.

I use it, however within a Thickbox (3.1) from the home site http://mydomain.
That doesn't work in IE8 (but only in the IE8 mode; IE7 and IE8-compatibility work fine) - the output is as attached.
No Javascript errors occur in the console.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be due to the lack of doctype declaration.

Adding

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Still happens with <!DOCTYPE html> declared. Any ideas?